# Can SharePoint 2019 recognize users thru On-Premise Data Gateway?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powerapps-forms, on-premise-data-gateway

We have a SP2019 setup for test purpose. Then we install on-premise data gateway in the environment. We can successfully connect the SharePoint data on-premise to Power Platform. Users can login PowerApps (vai userID@myfirm.com) can read/write/delete the data on-premise thru PowerApps.

However, we see the the "modified by" are the service account (mydomain\serviceaccount) we used to setup data gateway. Is it possible SharePoint 2019 can recognize the user who is using PowerApp to update the data?

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior that SharePoint on-premises (2019) will use the user account from the **Connections** in the Data Gateway. It can either be service account or system account (from my test result).

The Online accounts would not be recognized or even used since they need to create a connection first using this service account to access SharePoint on-premises.

[image]

Another reference on data gateway configuration: [Definitive Guide to Implement On-premises Data Gateway (Enterprise Mode) in Organisations.](https://www.biinsight.com/definitive-guide-to-implement-on-premises-data-gateway-enterprise-mode-in-organisations/)